# Tight upper bound: Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$; $\alpha, \beta> 0$, then $\alpha \| x-y\|_2^2 + \beta \| z - y \|_2^2\leq ?$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Tight upper bound: Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$; $\alpha, \beta > 0$, then I would like to find a (possibly tight) upper bound, i.e., the right hand side of the inequality

$$\alpha \| x-y\|_2^2 + \beta  \| z - y \|_2^2 \ {\color{green}{\leq}} \ { \color{red}{ \gamma \left( \| x - y \|_2^2  + \| x - z \|_2^2 \right)} {\color{blue}{+ \mu \| z - y \|_2^2} }}  ?$$

> More precisely, I would like to find $\gamma > 0$ and $\mu > 0$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The easiest would be to set $\gamma = \alpha$ and $\mu = \beta$, agreed?  Can we do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to find the bound to hold for all possible value of $x,y,z,$, which would mean $\beta,\gamma$ would be independent of $x,y,z$, then the best you can do is only $\gamma = \alpha$ and $\mu = \beta,$ because you can take $x = z$
and write you write your inequality as:
$$\|x-z\|^2\geq \dfrac{\alpha-\gamma}{\gamma}\|x-y\|^2+\dfrac{\beta - \mu}{\gamma}\|y-z\|^2 \,\,\,(1).$$

But $x,y,z$ are fixed, then $\gamma,\mu$ obviously must be chosen to be dependent on them to make sense. However, in that case the sense in which you can do "better" is a bit vague. You can get tighter $\gamma$ by by letting $\mu = \beta$ and then taking:
$$\gamma = \dfrac{\alpha\|x-y\|^2}{\|x-y\|^2+\|x-z\|^2} < \alpha.$$
Or you can sacrifice $\gamma$ and then get a better $\mu$ and so on.

If you have some unified sense of cost that combines $C = C(\gamma,\mu),$ then you can turn this into an optimization problem:
$$\min C(\gamma,\mu)\quad\text{subject to } (1)$$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.